# JetBrains Intellij macOS light theme for Xcode

Tags: xcode, intellij-idea, themes, iterm2

I am currently using the macOS Light theme in my IntelliJ.

When I press System Preferences -> Appearance and Behavior -> Appearance -> Theme, I can see macOS Light. I am also using light mode on my machine.

I m quite interested in the same theme, but for Xcode. I could not find anything on the web.

So I wanted to ask this quick question, what would be the Xcode setting in order to have the theme/look in Xcode please?

Maybe there is an already available version to download for Xcode?

(And preferably iTerm2 as well)

Thank you

Comment: When I switch my mac to light mode, Xcode automatically selects the light theme for me. What do you mean? Could you provide some images that depict what you're looking for?

Comment: Agree with you @gmdev, I am not saying my Mac does not detect light mode. What I mean is that the default Xcode light them on Mac is very pinkish color. I would like my Xcode on Max to just have the same blueish feel, the same as JetBrains. What would be the color setting to import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't actually change the theme of the Xcode IDE itself. However, there exists the ability to customize the fonts and colors of the editor and console. I threw together a very similar theme with the exact same colors as the Intellij basic light theme on macOS. You can copy and paste the xml below into any text editor and save the file as:

> YourThemeName.xccolortheme

Then drag and drop that file into this directory on macOS:

```
~Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes
```

If you are unsatisfied with some of the colors, fonts, font-weight, spacing, etc., you can change that by heading to Xcode and editing the specific elements by going to Editor > Themes > Edit Themes...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>DVTConsoleDebuggerInputTextColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleDebuggerInputTextFont</key>
    <string>SFMono-Bold - 12.0</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleDebuggerOutputTextColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleDebuggerOutputTextFont</key>
    <string>SFMono-Medium - 12.0</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleDebuggerPromptTextColor</key>
    <string>0.317071 0.437736 1 1</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleDebuggerPromptTextFont</key>
    <string>SFMono-Bold - 12.0</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleExectuableInputTextColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleExectuableInputTextFont</key>
    <string>SFMono-Medium - 12.0</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleExectuableOutputTextColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleExectuableOutputTextFont</key>
    <string>SFMono-Bold - 12.0</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleTextBackgroundColor</key>
    <string>1 1 1 1</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleTextInsertionPointColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTConsoleTextSelectionColor</key>
    <string>0.642038 0.802669 0.999195 1</string>
    <key>DVTDebuggerInstructionPointerColor</key>
    <string>0.705792 0.8 0.544 1</string>
    <key>DVTFontAndColorVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextBackgroundColor</key>
    <string>0.96 0.96 0.96 1</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextBorderColor</key>
    <string>0.8832 0.8832 0.8832 1</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextCodeFont</key>
    <string>SFMono-Regular - 10.0</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextEmphasisColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextEmphasisFont</key>
    <string>.AppleSystemUIFontItalic - 10.0</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextInlineCodeColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 0.7</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextLinkColor</key>
    <string>0.055 0.055 1 1</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextLinkFont</key>
    <string>.AppleSystemUIFont - 10.0</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextNormalColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextNormalFont</key>
    <string>.AppleSystemUIFont - 10.0</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextOtherHeadingColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 0.5</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextOtherHeadingFont</key>
    <string>.AppleSystemUIFont - 14.0</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextPrimaryHeadingColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextPrimaryHeadingFont</key>
    <string>.AppleSystemUIFont - 24.0</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextSecondaryHeadingColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextSecondaryHeadingFont</key>
    <string>.AppleSystemUIFont - 18.0</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextStrongColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTMarkupTextStrongFont</key>
    <string>.AppleSystemUIFontBold - 10.0</string>
    <key>DVTScrollbarMarkerAnalyzerColor</key>
    <string>0.403922 0.372549 1 1</string>
    <key>DVTScrollbarMarkerBreakpointColor</key>
    <string>0.290196 0.290196 0.968627 1</string>
    <key>DVTScrollbarMarkerDiffColor</key>
    <string>0.556863 0.556863 0.556863 1</string>
    <key>DVTScrollbarMarkerDiffConflictColor</key>
    <string>0.968627 0.290196 0.290196 1</string>
    <key>DVTScrollbarMarkerErrorColor</key>
    <string>0.968627 0.290196 0.290196 1</string>
    <key>DVTScrollbarMarkerRuntimeIssueColor</key>
    <string>0.643137 0.509804 1 1</string>
    <key>DVTScrollbarMarkerWarningColor</key>
    <string>0.937255 0.717647 0.34902 1</string>
    <key>DVTSourceTextBackground</key>
    <string>1 1 1 1</string>
    <key>DVTSourceTextBlockDimBackgroundColor</key>
    <string>0.424672 0.424672 0.424672 1</string>
    <key>DVTSourceTextCurrentLineHighlightColor</key>
    <string>1 0.984314 0.898039 1</string>
    <key>DVTSourceTextInsertionPointColor</key>
    <string>0 0 0 1</string>
    <key>DVTSourceTextInvisiblesColor</key>
    <string>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</string>
    <key>DVTSourceTextSelectionColor</key>
    <string>0.392157 0.498039 0.717647 1</string>
    <key>DVTSourceTextSyntaxColors</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xcode.syntax.attribute</key>
        <string>0.505801 0.371396 0.012096 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.character</key>
        <string>0.11 0 0.81 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.comment</key>
        <string>0.568627 0.568627 0.568627 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.comment.doc</key>
        <string>0.568627 0.568627 0.568627 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.comment.doc.keyword</key>
        <string>0.568627 0.568627 0.568627 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.declaration.other</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.declaration.type</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.class</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.class.system</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.constant</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.constant.system</key>
        <string>0.568627 0.568627 0.568627 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.function</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.function.system</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.macro</key>
        <string>0.391471 0.220311 0.124457 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.macro.system</key>
        <string>0.391471 0.220311 0.124457 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.type</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.type.system</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.variable</key>
        <string>0.0862745 0.0862745 0.0862745 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.variable.system</key>
        <string>0.447059 0.027451 0.533333 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.keyword</key>
        <string>0.00784314 0.00392157 0.560784 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.mark</key>
        <string>0.568627 0.568627 0.568627 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.markup.code</key>
        <string>0.665 0.052 0.569 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.number</key>
        <string>0.027451 0.0196078 0.972549 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.plain</key>
        <string>0 0 0 0.85</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.preprocessor</key>
        <string>0.391471 0.220311 0.124457 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.string</key>
        <string>0.0588235 0.54902 0.117647 1</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.url</key>
        <string>0.055 0.055 1 1</string>
    </dict>
    <key>DVTSourceTextSyntaxFonts</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xcode.syntax.attribute</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.character</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.comment</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.comment.doc</key>
        <string>HelveticaNeue - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.comment.doc.keyword</key>
        <string>SFMono-Bold - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.declaration.other</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.declaration.type</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.class</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.class.system</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.constant</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.constant.system</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.function</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.function.system</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.macro</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.macro.system</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.type</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.type.system</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.variable</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.variable.system</key>
        <string>SFMono-Semibold - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.keyword</key>
        <string>SFMono-Semibold - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.mark</key>
        <string>SFMono-Bold - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.markup.code</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.number</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.plain</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.preprocessor</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.string</key>
        <string>SFMono-Medium - 12.0</string>
        <key>xcode.syntax.url</key>
        <string>SFMono-Regular - 12.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```